# blender not responding while pinning the image in facebuilder addon

Tags: mesh

When I use blender it works properly but when I use the face builder add on and try to view and pin the image, the blender stops responding .Please help me.I repaired the blender software,ran blender as administrator ,but still it is not responding while doing the task

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a video card that does not support the necessary OpenGL shaders. You must reinstall the video drivers. But you can’t do anything with some graphics cards such as those made by Intel.